# aws ec2 tsc javascript heap out of memory

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, docker, tsc

I am currently deploying a Node.js server using AWS EC2 t2.micro, Docker.

I build a typescript file with `tsc` and try to run the built file directly.

However, at the time of using the tsc command, a javascript heap out of memory error occurs.

```
<--- Last few GCs --->
lo[29:0x5f661f0]    18203 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 489.2 (491.1) -> 488.3 (492.4) MB, 709.8 / 0.0 ms  (+ 0.1 ms in 16 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 728 ms) (average mu = 0.243, current mu = 0.025) allocati[29:0x5f661f0]    18935 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 489.4 (491.4) -> 488.8 (492.9) MB, 713.0 / 0.0 ms  (+ 0.1 ms in 17 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 732 ms) (average mu = 0.139, current mu = 0.026) allocati

<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0xa04200 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x94e4e9 node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [node]
 3: 0xb7978e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 4: 0xb79b07 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 5: 0xd34395  [node]
 6: 0xd64f2e v8::internal::EvacuateNewSpaceVisitor::Visit(v8::internal::HeapObject, int) [node]
 7: 0xd70f66 v8::internal::FullEvacuator::RawEvacuatePage(v8::internal::MemoryChunk*, long*) [node]
 8: 0xd5d14f v8::internal::Evacuator::EvacuatePage(v8::internal::MemoryChunk*) [node]
 9: 0xd5d3c8 v8::internal::PageEvacuationTask::RunInParallel(v8::internal::ItemParallelJob::Task::Runner) [node]
10: 0xd4fca9 v8::internal::ItemParallelJob::Run() [node]
11: 0xd72ec0 void v8::internal::MarkCompactCollectorBase::CreateAndExecuteEvacuationTasks<v8::internal::FullEvacuator, v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector>(v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector*, v8::internal::ItemParallelJob*, v8::internal::MigrationObserver*, long) [node]
12: 0xd7375c v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::EvacuatePagesInParallel() [node]
13: 0xd73925 v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::Evacuate() [node]
14: 0xd85911 v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::CollectGarbage() [node]
15: 0xd41c38 v8::internal::Heap::MarkCompact() [node]
16: 0xd43728 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
17: 0xd46b6c v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
18: 0xd0c472 v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRaw(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
19: 0xd086c2 v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::AllocateRawArray(int, v8::internal::AllocationType) [node]
20: 0xd08774 v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewFixedArrayWithFiller(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Map>, int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Oddball>, v8::internal::AllocationType) [node]
21: 0xf4ef4b v8::internal::OrderedHashTable<v8::internal::OrderedHashSet, 1>::Allocate(v8::internal::Isolate*, int, v8::internal::AllocationType) [node]
22: 0xf4f0df v8::internal::OrderedHashTable<v8::internal::OrderedHashSet, 1>::Rehash(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::OrderedHashSet>, int) [node]
23: 0x103eb98 v8::internal::Runtime_SetGrow(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
24: 0x1401219  [node]
Aborted (core dumped)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 134
npm ERR! share_up@1.0.0 build: `rimraf dist && tsc -p tsconfig.json`
npm ERR! Exit status 134
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the share_up@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-04-09T02_15_25_430Z-debug.log
```

This is error message

How can I fix this?

Comment: t2.micro has only 1gb o ram. If its not enough, why not something bigger?

Comment: Because I am developing this for study purposes, so I am using aws free tier.

Comment: I see. Can you build it on your local workstation then, and then just use pre-build app on the instance?

Comment: Yes. There is no error when running the locally built file in the instance as it is. By the way, I upload a file to GitHub and get a pull and use it. Can I upload the built files to GitHub?